# Prime gap heuristics (follows up my question "Moments of merit")

Tags: nt.number-theory, pr.probability

I previously asked generally what people knew or conjectured concerning the moments of the probability distribution governing $M_n:= g_n/\ln(p_n)$, the normalized $n$th prime gap (or ``merit'').  Greg Martin pointed out that existing conjectures rest on the modeling as a Poisson process occurances of normalized primes $p_n/ln(p_n)$ in short intervals.   Thus in the limit an exponential distribution of mean 1 ought to govern merit.  In particular the variance of merit (around 0, so $E(M_n^2)$) should converge on 2.

Now exponential distributions arise here, as they normally do, as limits of geometric distributions - on making the probability of success go to zero, but increasing the rapidity of the trials to compensate.  "Success" here means that a number $m$ belongs to the primes, so the probability of success , $1/\ln m$ falls very slowly.  That slow decrease means that for numeric testing, one should ignore the Poisson limit, and compare rather directly with a geometric distribution.

An exponential distribution with success probability $p$ has mean $1/p$ and variance (around 0) $(2-p)/p^2$.  Adjusting the trial frequency to make the mean time to success $1$ makes the variance $2-p$.

My question: Can anyone explain, heuristically at least, why this doesn't jive with experiment?  Computing all gaps for primes up to 480,000,000, I got a sample variance of about 1.73,  where the model would predict about 1.947.  I've seen the same size discrepancy over short intervals, so it seem robust.  Higher moments seem similarly depressed.

Comment: Can you say exactly what you computed?

Comment: $\frac{1}{\pi(N)}\sum_{p_n<N} \left(\frac{p_{n+1}-p_n}{\ln(p_n)}\right)^2$ for N=480000000

Comment: Maybe a factor  $ 2e^{-\gamma}\approx 1.947/1.73 $ should be taken into account

Comment: That's fabulous!  But what's the heuristic?

Comment: Sylvain JULIEN - If that numerology is real, wouldn't one expect it to persist all the way to the limit so that the variance of merit would equal 1.78107..., not 2 as predicted by the Poisson model????  That strikes me as potentially very interesting if Greg Martin is correct that Gallagher verified the Poisson model from standard conjectures about $k$-tuples.  Or am I missing something??

Comment: Model 10 here: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/01/04/254a-supplement-4-probabilistic-models-and-heuristics-for-the-primes-optional/

Comment: I thought about something like Model 10, but I can't figure out how to make it work...in particular it seems well adapted to gaps of an absolute size, but what do with normalized gaps doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: Wouldn't Model 10 want to speak to the ratio $(2-1.73)/(2-1.947)$ instead of the one above?

Comment: A baby version of Model 10 would take account of the oddness of large primes.  So odd numbers x are prime with probability 2/ln x, and that would reduce the sample variance prediction from 1-1/lnx down to 1-2/lnx, like half as many trials with twice the probability.  But already the prime 3 requires revising the metaphors...the trials no longer come at a steady tempo...and then it just gets worse and worse with higher primes.

Comment: There are lower order terms here that one can compute using the Hardy Littlewood conjectures.  For example see the paper of Lemke Oliver and Soundararajan for a related calculation.  In this situation there is a secondary term of size $-2\log \log N/\log N$ which should account for this (and also extra terms of size $1/\log N$).  I'm a bit busy now, but I'll try post something in a few days.